# Is it possible to open a menu when a button is clicked in Rad Studio

Tags: c++builder

It is possible to do in most other environments, but i'm unable to find a way to do this with Embarcadero.

The closest thing that was found is setting the `DropDownMenu` property on a button with `bsSplitButton` property... however this has a problem that it only works with Vista (so in fact i cannot even test if it works at all).

Alternatively it is currently possible to add a regular right button drop down.

Is there a way to connect button's left button click event to a specific drop down menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button's `OnClick` event handler can call the `Popup()` method of a `TPopupMenu` component.  You do not have to assign the `PopupMenu` to the button unless you want it to handle right-clicking.